# Multiplicities of points on a projective curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry, curves, projective-space

I want to understand the process of determining simple/multiple points of projective curves.

Say $F(X,Y,Z)$ is a homogeneous polynomial; it defines a curve, and by abuse of language I will refer to this curve as $F$. Fulton's book says that the multiplicity of $F$ at $P$ of $Z$ is by definition the multiplicity of $F_\ast$ at $P$, where $F_\ast=F(X,Y,1$). But in the former case $P$ is a point in $\mathbb{P}^2$ whereas in the latter case $P$ is a point in $\mathbb{A}^2$. So I'm confused.

Could you write a simple example of determining simple/multiple points of a projective curve? You may assume I know how to determine such points on affine curves by Fulton's algorithm (see my previous question [Multiplicity of a point on an affine curve that is not the origin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2202464/multiplicity-of-a-point-on-an-affine-curve-that-is-not-the-origin))

Comment: This is because $\mathbb{P}^2$ is covered by three open subsets which are isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^2$. If you are not familiar with this fact, you should read about the projective plane.

Comment: So I need to find simple/multiple points of each of the three polynomials $F(1,Y,Z), F(X,1,Z), F(X,Y,1)$ and then if e.g. $(y,z)$ is a multiple point of $F(1,Y,Z)$ then this will correspond to the fact $[1:y:z]$ is a multiple point of $F(X,Y,Z)$?

Comment: Yes that's it. Work out some examples.